# How to use virtual floppy drive on windows 10 64 bit?

Tags: windows, floppy

I want to install images of 1.44 floppy disks.
These images come with a program called vfd.

The install with

```
vfd.exe install
```

works fine.

The required

```
vfd.exe starts
```

aborts with the message

```
Failed to start the Virtual FD driver. This driver has been blocked from loading.
```

I did this from a cmd.exe with Admin Privileges.

Any suggestions ??

Comment: If the driver is not signed and you are using a 64-bit version of Windows 10 then you will have to disabled driver enforcement to use unsigned drivers

Comment: That is one route I'll follow.

Answer (score 2):

[vfd.exe](http://vfd.sourceforge.net/) states

> This is a virtual floppy drive for Windows NT / 2000 / XP developed by Ken Kato
>   (Reported to work also on 2003 Server and Vista).
>   **Note !!! This version works only on 32 bit systems !!!**

There looks to be some info there but considering the changelog for the latest version states `Added platform checking so that VFD does not start on 64 bit OS.` you may be out of luck with the version you have.

Unless you are comfortable compiling from source or are willing to trust a [patched executable](http://vfd.sourceforge.net/#w64bit) submitted from a single person on the internet then you may be out of luck as this software appears abandoned.

You might have some luck extracting the disk files using something like 7-zip if they are in a standard disk image format.

Comment: Is it possible to create a 32 bit virtual machine on a 64 bit system ?

Comment: The files are designed to run a floppy drive, it is an install of a classic program.

Comment: @niloderoock it definitely is possible and would probably be the easiest way to get access. It's probably worth using Windows XP 32-bit for compatibility, if you can find or have access to a legitimate copy.